# sonar jdbc properties are not supported anymore in sonarqube 5.3 version

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarqube 5.3 latest version and when I configure the sonar jdbc properties in my properties file using

```
property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar")
property "sonar.jdbc.username", "root")
property "sonar.jdbc.password", "root")
```

I get warning message

```
Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
Property 'sonar.jdbc.username' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
Property 'sonar.jdbc.password' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
```

How to configure external database and not use embedded database provided by sonarqube?

Answer (score 23):

You only need to configure the `sonar.host.url`. All communication between scanner and server is done with web services, and the scanner no longer talks to the database at all.

Comment: Currently I am also facing the same issue and is there any way I can connect to MySQL to store the details.This issue is happening only after upgrading to SonarQube 6