# Sonarqube: why: "H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only" when there is (evidently) a postgres connection?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

When I start the sonarqube 6.1 server, the log contains the message "H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only".  However, the log also indicates that evidently sonarqube is correctly connecting to postgres.  Furthermore, this post [sonar jdbc properties are not supported anymore in sonarqube 5.3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230453/sonar-jdbc-properties-are-not-supported-anymore-in-sonarqube-5-3-version) indicates that the server doesn't talk to the database at all.  So what gives?  Is this message always put in the log, or do I need to pay attention?  Does the server currently connect to a database or not?

Comment: Please provide the logs you are referring to. The post you are referring to concerns the scanner. It does not apply to the server. The scanner doesn't talk to the database anymore since 5.2. But of course, the server still does.

Comment: Thanks, OK, I get it now.  Both scanner and server logs contain the comment I referred to.  Can you point me to some documentation that actually describes the architecture?

Comment: please provide the logs and more information about your setup if you expect any further help on this.

Comment: I get it now.  Thanks.