# SonarQube 6.0 with Sonar-Scanner-2.6.1 Cofinguration with MYSQL

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I was using SonarQube 5.1.2 with Sonar-runner-dist 2.4 but I have to upgrade my SonarQube to 6.0 along with Sonar-Scanner-2.6.1

I was using MySQL for SonarQube 5.1.2 but When I upgraded to SonarQube 6.0 I am getting this error , Can someone help me how to override the error and what changes required with SonarQube 6.0

Not Sure why I am getting

**WARN: Property 'sonar.jdbc.username' is not supported any more. It will be ignor
ed. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.**

**Complete Error Log**

```
WARN: sonar-runner.bat script is deprecated. Please use sonar-scanner.bat instea
d.
D:\Softwares\SonarQube_old\sonar-scanner-2.6.1\sonar-scanner-2.6.1
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
INFO: Scanner configuration file: D:\Softwares\SonarQube_old\sonar-scanner-2.6.1
\sonar-scanner-2.6.1\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1
INFO: Java 1.8.0_111 Oracle Corporation (32-bit)
INFO: Windows 7 6.1 x86
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\391007\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load global repositories
INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=124ms
WARN: Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. T
here is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
WARN: Property 'sonar.jdbc.username' is not supported any more. It will be ignor
ed. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
WARN: Property 'sonar.jdbc.password' is not supported any more. It will be ignor
ed. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\391007\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=9ms
INFO: SonarQube server 6.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is
platform dependent)
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2.553s
INFO: Final Memory: 40M/96M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to register extension com.sonar.governance.task.A.A from plugin 'g
overnance'
ERROR: Caused by: Lorg/sonar/batch/bootstrap/BatchWsClient;
ERROR: Caused by: org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient
ERROR:
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Scanner with
the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging
```

I have referred below Answer but I am not getting solution to solve the problem

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35231407/3973543

Answer (score 1):

"WARN: Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more " is not an error, just a warning, since 5.6 sonar.jdbc.url, sonar.jdbc.username and sonar.jdbc.password are not needed anymore in jenkins side. The sonarqube DataBase is only access from sonarqube instance, not from the clients as jenkins. So you should let them empty now. Just fill the sonarqube instance url for the WS connection.

Governance plugin is now commercial, you have to registry a license for using it

Comment: Sure I will try this one what is WS connection here

Comment: BTW, Governance has _always_ been commercial. :)

Comment: Note that at the time of writing the Governance plugin is not yet compatible with 6.x series of SonarQube. It should be uninstalled. Please contact the SonarSource support team for more information.

Comment: @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource@G. Ann - SonarSource Team Can you please let me what is WS connection means how to setup is there any tutorials to follow.

Comment: @Batman in jenkins configuration you have a 'sonar' part, you can set your sonarqube installations (many as you want) for each you can set a name, .., and the url where sonarqube instance can be reach. It is use by jenkins for posting data as a webservice flow.